# run exe file in user system from the browser using java

Tags: java

I have an exe file in the user system . When ever user clicks on a button in the application(application runs in server machine) from the browser I need to execute  the exe file in the user system .

Could you please help me to do it .

Comment: I sincerely hope this is not possible. It would be a security nightmare.

Comment: By browser, you mean web browser ?

Comment: I planned to do using applet . But we can't use applet in latest browser .yes , By web browser .

Comment: You can trigger one event to back end from the UI, could be an AJAX call when you click the button and then at Java side, you use Java native "Runtime" and "Process" class to invoke the executables. Well, you need to take care of security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if your exe file supports browser links via a specific protocole.

For example, this is used to launch skype with JavaScript

```
window.location = 'skype:user?chat';
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible using an  link or similar. If the executable you wish to run is a program your company requires the user to download and install from your site, you could also try installing a file system handler.

Both of these ways require user permission (which is an obvious necessity for security reasons).